Trying to decode a data structure from a COM structured storage stream
I have a CAD file that is a COM structured storage file. One of the streams in this file contains some configuration data. I can see the ASCII strings that have the descriptions of the data I'm looking for. One example:
17 00 00 00 53 00 69 00 6D 00 70 00 6C 00 69 00
66 00 79 00 42 00 73 00 70 00 6C 00 69 00 6E 00
65 00 73 00 4F 00 70 00 74 00 69 00 6F 00 6E 00
5F 00 00 00 00 00 00 F2 00 00 00 0F 00 00 00 52

In this hex you can see the text SimplifyBsplinesOption. SimplifyBsplinesOption should be a check box.
00 00 00 FB 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 4D 00 69 00 6E
00 69 00 6D 00 75 00 6D 00 41 00 72 00 63 00 4C
00 65 00 6E 00 67 00 74 00 68 00 01 00 00 00 04
00 00 00 0D 00 00 00 01 FC 00 00 00 11 00 00 00
4D 00 69 00 6E 00 69 00 6D 00 75 00 6D 00 41 00
72 00 63 00 4C 00 65 00 6E 00 67 00 74 00 68 00
5F 00 00 00 00 00 00 FE 00 00 00 14 00 00 00 44
00 65 00 76 00 69 00 61 00 74 00 69 00 6F 00 6E
00 61 00 6C 00 54 00 6F 00 6C 00 65 00 72 00 61
00 6E 00 63 00 65 00 01 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 0E
00 00 00 01 FF 00 00 00 15 00 00 00 44 00 65 00
76 00 69 00 61 00 74 00 69 00 6F 00 6E 00 61 00
6C 00 54 00 6F 00 6C 00 65 00 72 00 61 00 6E 00
63 00 65 00 5F 00 00 00 00 00 00 4F 01 00 00 23
00 00 00 46 00 6C 00 61 00 74 00 5F 00 50 00 61

In this block you can see "MinimumArcLength" and "DeviationalTolerance" strings.
MinimumArcLength and DeviationalTolerance are values measured in thousandths of an inch. I know behind the scenes in the API, the software stores all linear spacial measurements in meters. I thought it interesting that in the first hex block, F2 represents -2.53530120045646E30 as a float32 because 1 inch is 0.0254 meters. This value doesn't change based on any settings. I'm guessing it's like a unit of measurement multiplier or a coincidence. I guess it's not really relevant to the actual problem though.
I created three files by changing the min arc length and deviational tolerance to different values.
Attached to this Github issue you can see the files I'm working with in the PSMclusterVariance.zip file. The only changes to the files are the -001 file has the minimum arc and deviational tolerance set to 0.001". -005 is 0.005", and -1000 is 1"
I am expecting to see these values in meters, so something close to or computable to 0.0000254, 0.000127, and 0.0254 in the respective files. I found them stored in close proximity just before one of the instances of the description strings.

By changing these bytes to a float64 of 0.007 and importing the stream back into the CAD file I was able to determine that this is the Deviational Tolerance value as it showed the new value in the GUI. So I'm close-ish. I need to figure out how to check the box that enables the minimum arc and deviational tolerance settings in the first place. I've tried doing compare searches in HxD to find differences, but I can't find anything that stands out as the (presumably bool) flag that enables the options. Enough changes in the file simply changing that setting and saving that I'm having trouble doing a good comparison. I've also uploaded to the Github issue a PSMcluster0-off file which is the state of the file when the box is unchecked. I think I'm going to have to understand the larger data organization scheme before I find the part of the file to turn it on. I'll also need to understand the overall data structure to safely change the values from my library.
What should my next steps be? I've ran this data through tools like trid and foremost and it doesn't pick up any known signatures. I'm excited to have found the values I want to change, but I'm about at the extent of my knowledge here. Any guidance would be appreciated.

I created a .par with a sketch and a protrusion  and saved all the streams 26 streams in total opened again changed protrusion depth resaved and saved 26 stream again. Dumped both into winmerge and i onserve 6 streams are different and have very large changes  just could comfirm that the dimension is stored as double float64  other than that it does not appear the resource modification is stored in .par file  and only the par file appears to be com storafe the streams may be in an app understandabke format

To add to blabb's comment, some of the streams also contain references to other stream names which implies a relationship across multiple streams. So, you might not find all your data in a single stream, but rather spread through multiple streams in a doc.
In structured-storage, although an IStore ("directory" from your terminology used on GH) can be used to store data that is related, it doesn't actually have to and can be app-specific. i.e. "PSMclustertable", may ref names for a cluster table, but their attribs could be in "Unclustered Dynamic Attributes", or even outside the document.

Appears that Okino.com has a product, Nugraf and Polytrans, with a demo and a single dll (SEPartReader) if you're interested in reversing/debugging. You'd start with a breakpoint at StgOpenStorageSomething, then that'll spit out a reference to an IStorage interface. From that you can breakpoint on each of its methods to figure out which IStream it opens to figure out the correct workflow.

@AliRizvi-Santiago Thank you for the tips. I'll give it a deeper look, but I believe that software is simply extracting the parasolid data (the streams in the PARASOLID storage) from the native files. This is where all the modeling information is stored. I'm also looking to grab that but there are a lot of resources to pull from already there like open libraries that support the format.
The target I'm looking for is a Solid Edge specific property that controls how Solid Edge approximates splines to lines and arcs while generating an unrolled model from a part with curves.
